# Create folder in Android in DCIM folder (Sorry, another one.)

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

Ok, I'm making a game in Unity and I'm trying to take a screenshot and save it into a folder I create in the DCIM folder. I tried creating the folder in Unity but it never worked.
I tried creating a plugin in Android studio to do it, also with no luck.

Here is my Java code:

```
package foldercreator.TehBestCompany.com.foldermakerlibrary;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.String;


public class FolderMaker {

    public boolean MoveFile( String filename, String sourceFolder, String destinationFolder )
    {
        String fullDestinationFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString() + "/" + destinationFolder;

        Log( "Destination folder " + fullDestinationFolder);

        final File f = new File( fullDestinationFolder );

        if (!f.exists()) {
            Log( "Folder doesn't exist, creating it...");
            boolean rv = f.mkdir();
            Log( "Folder creation " + ( rv ? "success" : "failed"));
        } else {
            Log( "Folder already exists.");
        }

        return true;
    }



    private void Log( String message )
    {
        Log.d("[LOG FILE]", message );
        System.out.println( "[LOG FILE] " + message );
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I always get a 'Folder creation failed' message.

Here's my library manifest (I've checked the uses external storage option in Unity if it helps):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="foldercreator.TehBestCompany.com.foldermakerlibrary" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Can someone give me some advice?

I know this question's been asked many times before, but after a full day of trying various solutions, I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when i change this line:

```
String fullDestinationFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString() + "/" + destinationFolder;
```

To:

```
String fullDestinationFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)+"/destenationFolder");
```

And then :

```
File fileName = new File(fullDesinationFolder, "screenshot.jpeg");
```

Or just do straight away:

```
File fileName = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)+"/destenationFolder"), "screenshot.jpeg");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I can't do your first suggestion (I.E.)
`...DIRECTORY_DCIM)+"/destenationFolder");`
because destinationFolder is passed into this plugin by unity, so has to be constructed as I did in my code.

As for your second suggestion, you suggest creating a file, then checking if it exists, but it'll never exist, because I haven't moved it there yet. I'm trying to create the destination folder to move the file to.

Comment: It is not working also when you don't add `.toString()`? (after `DIRECTORY_DCIM`)

Comment: No. I did this and still get a Folder creation failed message.

`String fullDestinationFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/" + destinationFolder;

        final File f = new File( fullDestinationFolder, filename );

        if (!f.exists()) {
            Log( "Folder doesn't exist, creating it...");
            boolean rv = f.mkdirs();
            Log( "Folder creation " + ( rv ? "success" : "failed"));
        } else {
            Log( "Folder already exists.");
        }`

Comment: I see that you close your brackets after `DIRECTORY_DCIM`...

Don't close your brackets until after `destinationFolder`...

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/" + destinationFolder)`

Comment: Tried this, still doesn't work.

    final File f = new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/" + destinationFolder), filename );

    if (!f.exists()) {
     Log( "Folder doesn't exist, creating it...");
     boolean rv = f.mkdirs();  
     Log( "Folder creation " + ( rv ? "success" : "failed"));
     if( !rv ) return false;
    } else {
        Log( "Folder already exists.");
    }

Comment: Try this `File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)), "destenationFolder");
if(!directory.exsist() {Log( "Folder doesn't exist, creating it...")

if(!directory.mkdirs() {....}}`

Comment: Could it be a permission thing? I'm not sure if my library manifest is correct or if I've set everything I need to in Unity?

Comment: Oh, yes, you need to ask the user premmision for read/write from external storage<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Already had write storage, tried with read storage as well with no luck.